# S-Video to 2 RCA

Tags: connection, nvidia-geforce, s-video

I have: `GeForce 8500 GT` with S-Video 7-pin output and u have assimilator to 4 pins. I plug 2 RCA on my TV for A/V inputs, switch to AV2 input, the PC screen flashes for a second plays the sound for new device attached but nothing on the TV...

What's going on?

Comment: S-video and RCA are both composite connections and only require an adapter to interchange. It should be a one to one ratio for video connectors.

Comment: S-Video is not a composite connection. You'll need a S-Video to composite signal converter/adapter which are usually inexpensive and can be found at many electronics retailers.

Comment: But I have everything the converter from Gigabyte and cabel. Now when I try to detect new monitor, part of the desktop shows on the TV and disappears quickly...

Answer (score 2):

Nikola,

I have the 8800GTX and I fought the exact same issue you are describing.  I finally found a three step process to get it to work.

1. Activate the TV as my 2nd monitor under "Display Properties".
2. Reboot.
3. Watch and enjoy.

NOTE:  Occassionaly, I would have to reboot twice and or play with the Screen order under windows.  Eventually, I did get it to work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How awesome that we have HDMI now. It sure was hard sometimes to get S-Video or composite to work.#